# Use AT&T assembly to read from STDIN, crash at _start(), why?

Tags: linux, assembly, crash, system-calls, att

I wish to read from STDIN(fd=0) from system call(SYSREAD=3)，put the result into an array named "my_buffer当中":

```
.section .bss
.lcomm my_buffer,500
.globl _start
_start:
movl $mybuffer,%ecx
movl 500,%edx
movl $0,%ebx
movl $3,%eax
int $0x80
movl $1,%eax
int $0x80
```

It will crash. I used gdb to debug this core dump， show as below:

```
Core was generated by `h'.
Program terminated with signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
#0  0x0000000000600078 in _start ()
```

It's really weird, why it crashes at _start() entry point?

Comment: `movl 500,%edx` is the problem. Think you want `movl $500,%edx`. You should be able to use `gdb` to show you the instruction that is the problem. When the error occurs try using `layout asm` (`layout reg` should dump registers which can be useful)

Comment: As well you didn't place the code into the `.text` section. Just above your `_start` label place this line `.section .text` . You placed all your code in the `.bss` section which will cause serious problems.

Comment: This is a typo `movl $mybuffer,%ecx` think you meant `movl $my_buffer,%ecx`

Comment: Thanks for all your 3 corrections. Now it works!